# ASP.Net MVC Dropdown text generation using a Select List not populating the values and text

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Using the following code i generate a select list in my controller and feed it into my view model.

```
var SelectListItems = om_repo.List().Select(x => {
            var item = new SelectListItem();
            item.Value = x.id.ToString();
            item.Text = x.code;
            return item;
        });

createvm.allOccupations = new SelectList(SelectListItems);
```

Here is my view code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedOccupation,  Model.allOccupations, "Choose one")
```

The output im getting is

```
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
```

Why isnt it picking up the select list items Text and Values that are being fed. In my debugger i can see the values are set in the locals under text and value.

[image]

Comment: Just to let you know your initial selector can be simplified to var SelectListItems = om_repo.List().Select(x => new SelectListItem{
            Value = x.id.ToString(),
            Text = x.code });

Comment: `SelectedListItems` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Its pointless to create another identical one from it. It's  just `createvm.allOccupations = SelectListItems;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the DropDownlist doesn't want a `SelectList`; it wants an `IEnumerable` of `SelectListItems`.

Try just:

```
createvm.allOccupations = SelectListItems;
```

Model Class also needs to be:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> allOccupations { get; set; }
```

Not

```
public SelectList allOccupations { get; set; }
```

Scott Allen expanded on the problem here: https://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2010/01/18/drop-down-lists-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: createvm.allOccupations = SelectListItems;

Gives me the following error.
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Change how it's defined in your Model class.

Comment: The property should be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` not `SelectList`!

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yup changing the model class to IEnumerable<SelectListItem> fixed it.